# cron job not working for xwindow

Tags: bash, cron

I have following line in crontab
*/1  *  *  *  *  xeyes

it does not show any xwindow but on the contrary
*/1  *  *  *  *  touch somefile.txt works fine

Tried to search on google but didnt get any specific answers!!

Comment: `env DISPLAY=:0 xeyes`

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell cron where to find the X server if the command you run uses it.

So use: `env DISPLAY=:0.0 xeyes` or `export DISPLAY=:0.0; xeyes`.

Some cron implementations (Debian, Ubuntu, ...) allows to set enviroment simply in cron file.

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1 * * * * xeyes
```